# PHP: Get Form inputs

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have a forms like this

```
<input type="text" name="question[]" />
   <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
   <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<input type="text" name="question[]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
```

*Users can add or remove inputs dynamically.

I've tired

```
foreach($_POST['question_title'] as $question_key=>$question_title){ 
    echo $question_title.'<br>';
    foreach($_POST['answer_title'] as $answer_key=>$answer_title){ 
        echo $answer_title.'<br>';
    }
}
```

but i get

```
question 1
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 1
answer 2

question 2
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 1
answer 2
```

but i want the code to output

```
question 1
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3


question 2
answer 1
answer 2
```

*Results are input values.

thanks in advance.

Update: thanks for the downvote, it's a great community. I came here after many research and posted my codes. Thank you stackoverflow.

Comment: that kind of grouping is also possible, one of the possible answer may depend on how you create the question sets dynamically, you can post that part too

Comment: @ghost dynamic question set is the same as the above code, can add as much as question and answer. No numbering index

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<input type="text" name="question[1]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[1][]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[1][]" />
<input type="text" name="question[2]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[2][]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[2][]" />
    <input type="text" name="answer[2][]" />
```

And then

```
foreach($_POST['question_title'] as $question_key=>$question_title){ 
    echo $question_title.'<br>';
    foreach($_POST['answer_title'][$question_key] as $answer_key=>$answer_title){ 
        echo $answer_title.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: i would also do it this way, but you'll need to create that dynamic javascript function which creates add new row which introduces the numbering index

Comment: I tried the samething, didn't want to update the whole index every time an input is removed

Answer (score 0):

The questions/answers have the same name. You have to give them different names or PHP won't be able to tell you which answers are associated with which questions.

When you add a question/answer, make sure it's name is something along the lines of "`answer[question_id/index][]`" or "`question[id]`"